# Persisting an entity when ID is null and automatically generated in the database

Tags: java, jpa, derby, glassfish-4

I'm using EclipseLink with JavaDB and every time I try to persist a new user entity I get an error relating to the fact the ID field of the new user entity is null. I know it's null -- and it should be because the ID field is generated as the Identity in the database. Or am I wrong? I've tried adding @GeneratedValue to the entity but that causes errors regardless of the generation strategy used. I've also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759894/entitymanager-persist-method-does-not-insert-record-to-database), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087848/when-does-the-jpa-set-a-generatedvalue-id), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126129/persisting-entity-to-database-with-jpa-and-autogenerated-primary-key-identity) but these questions don't seem to relate fully to my issue. The exceptions below always occur on at the call to EntityManager.persist(user).

I also tried removing @NotNull and @GeneratedValue and, oddly enough, it got past the persist call -- but only to fail on the commit. As far as I can tell I've got everything set right. So the question is: why is this application failing to add a new user and what do I need to do to fix it?

User entity:

```
 @Entity(name = "User")
 @Table(name = "USERS")
 public class User implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @Id
     @Basic(optional = false)
     @NotNull
     @Column(name = "IDENTIFIER", nullable = false,unique = true)
     private Long identifier;
     // class shortened for brevity
}
```

Corresponding to this SQL Script:

```
create table "USERSDBADMIN".USERS
(
        IDENTIFIER BIGINT not null primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
            (START WITH 0, INCREMENT BY 1),
        USERNAME VARCHAR(50) not null,
        EMAIL VARCHAR(150) not null,
        LASTLOGIN DATE default NULL
);
```

User Create Method (from the JPA controller):

```
public void create(User user) throws PreexistingEntityException, RollbackFailureException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        utx.begin();
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.persist(user);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception re) {
            throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
        }
        if (findUser(user.getIdentifier()) != null) {
            throw new PreexistingEntityException("User " + user + " already exists.", ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

GenerationStrategy.Identity error (basically saying the ID field is null):

```
ex = (javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException) javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
```

GenerationStrategy.Sequence error (Table and Auto produce same exception):

```
ex = (org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException) Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException. Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SEQUENCE 'SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE' does not exist. Call: VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE) Query: ValueReadQuery(sql="VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE)")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not use `@NotNull` constraint on `@Id` attribute generated using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` strategy.
The problem is `@NotNull` and other `JSR-303` constraints are validated before commit.
And the autoincremented identifier isn't available until after the commit completes.

Try this and don't care about ID initialization any more:

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "IDENTIFIER", nullable = false, unique = true)
 private Long identifier;
```

Comment: This is a much better solution -- I really don't care about ID initialization anymore!. I should have tried it before posting -- but it works. Thank you @Lukas!

Comment: Alternatively, just use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, and you will never have to do anything else besides declaring `@Id` `@GeneratedValue`. If you are curious, more [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys/#GenerationTypeSEQUENCE).

Answer (score 0):

When I'm using auto increment at the identifier I do like this:

```
User user = new User();
user.setIdentifier((long) 0);// Assign 0 to ID for MSSQL/MySQL to properly auto_increment the primary key.
user.setUserName("some name");
...
```

With this Annotation for the id:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```

Comment: Welp that did it. But wtf man? Why do I have to set the ID field? I mean JPA should automatically set it.

Comment: I don't have to set the ID field -- see the accepted answer. Besides, setting the ID to zero will cause things to go screwy because I start my Identifier's with zero (see SQL). -1 could work but I never tried.